# How to add optional entries to Map in Scala?

Tags: scala, fold

Suppose I am adding an optional entry of type `Option[(Int, String)]` to `Map[Int, String]`

```
def foo(oe: Option[(Int, String)], map: Map[Int, String]) = oe.fold(map)(map + _)
```

Now I wonder how to add a *few* optional entries:

```
def foo(oe1: Option[(Int, String)],
        oe2: Option[(Int, String)],
        oe3: Option[(Int, String)],
        map: Map[Int, String]): Map[Int, String] = ???
```

How would you implement it ?

Comment: `map ++ oe1 ++ oe2 ++ oe3` works, but relies on some kind of unpleasant implicit conversions.

Comment: @TravisBrown I would argue that the implicit conversions are actually pleasant, not unpleasant. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: @Madoc My complaint doesn't have anything to do with optimization—it's about unpredictable magic that results in awful surprises like the return type of `Option(('a, 1)).unzip`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thank you. I guess `Option[A, B]` is implicitly converted to a `Map[A, B]` (`None` is converted to an empty map), so it seems reasonable ... but I don't like such magic either. On the other hand `map ++ oe1 ++ oe2 ++ oe3` looks so nice that I cannot resist it.

Comment: @Michael That's basically right—`Map`'s `++` takes a `GenTraversableOnce[(A, B)]`, and `Option.optionToIterable` will convert an `Option[(A, B)]` into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in a comment above, Scala provides an implicit conversion ([`option2Iterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option$)) that allows you to use `Option` as a collection of one or zero objects in the context of other types in the collection library.

This has some annoying consequences, but it does provide the following nice syntax for your operation:

```
def foo(oe1: Option[(Int, String)],
    oe2: Option[(Int, String)],
    oe3: Option[(Int, String)],
    map: Map[Int, String]): Map[Int, String] = map ++ oe1 ++ oe2 ++ oe3
```

This works because the `++` on `Map` takes an `GenTraversableOnce[(A, B)]`, and the `Iterable` that you get from `option2Iterable` is a subtype of `GenTraversableOnce`.

There are lots of variations on this approach. You could also write `map ++ Seq(oe1, oe2, oe3).flatten`, for example. I find that less clear, and it involves the creation of an extra collection, but if you like it, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
map ++ Seq(oe1, oe2, oe3).flatten
```

Comment: Sorry, even if this answer included some context, I don't see any reason to choose this over `map ++ oe1 ++ oe2 ++ oe3`. It's more verbose, less clear, and (least importantly) less efficient.

Comment: @TravisBrown can you explain why it is less efficient?

Comment: It's creating a collection and then applying an implicit conversion to each of it's elements, instead of simply applying the conversion for each of the `++` calls.

Comment: @TravisBrown This kind of "efficiency" concern does not matter. Sparing out the creation of one temporary sequence per three entries added to a map is really premature optimization. Also I don't see why it should be necessary to give a "reason to choose this over `map ++ oe1 ++ oe2 ++ oe3`". This is the way I would solve it; I wouldn't repeat the `++` operator. But it's just a question of taste really, and the reader can choose what she thinks it best.

Comment: @Madoc Agreed—the "less efficient" part was a joke about worrying about optimization. This just isn't a very good answer—there are several complex things here that you don't explain at all, and you've made the situation more complex by adding a `flatten` operation. If you prefer that for stylistic reasons, fine, but explain that—don't just drop some code on the page.

Comment: @TravisBrown If the question is "How would you implement...?", the answer can well be "some code" that I "just drop" on the page. Especially when it's trivial like this, it shouldn't require further commenting. `flatten` is part of the standard library and already well documented. I don't think an answer must necessarily restate what is already well written down in the official documentation. Asking questions about the answer and clarifying - that's what the comments are there for. No need for the author to clarify questions before they were asked -> different form of premature optimization!

Answer (score 0):

If the number of optional entries is variable I would use variable length arguments

```
def foo(map: Map[Int, String], os: Option[(Int, String)]*) = map ++ os.flatten
```

Comment: This is a reasonable answer to a different question.

Comment: Which might be a better alternative.